# how to write the pivot_table to txt file by python

Tags: python, pandas

I have get the pivot_table as follows:

[image: source table]

there are spaces in the table,
what i want to write to txt is:

[image: desired result]

how to get it ?

```
chaoshidishi=pd.pivot_table(clsc,index="故障发生地市",values="工单号",aggfunc=len)
chaoshidishi=chaoshidishi.to_frame()
f=open('E:\gaotie\dishi.txt','w')
for row in chaoshidishi:
    f.write(row[0]+row[1])
f.close()
```

Comment: Why dont you use [DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) function

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @shanmuga's comment, you should be able to use `to_csv()` without first using `to_frame()`.

First, here's some sample data that seems to reflect your setup:

```
import pandas as pd

group = ['a','a','b','c','c']
value = [1,2,3,4,5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':group,'value':value})
print(df)

  group  value
0     a      1
1     a      2
2     b      3
3     c      4
4     c      5
```

Now apply `pivot_table()`:

```
df.pivot_table(columns='group', values='value', aggfunc=len)

group
a    2
b    1
c    2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

You can save to file directly from this output.  If you don't want to preserve index and column names, use `header=None` on load:

```
(df.pivot_table(columns='group', values='value', aggfunc=len)
   .to_csv('foo.txt'))
newdf = pd.read_csv('foo.txt', header=None)

print(newdf)

   0  1
0  a  2
1  b  1
2  c  2
```

To preserve column and index names, use the `header` argument on save, and the `index_col` argument on load:

```
(df.pivot_table(columns='group', values='value', aggfunc=len)
   .to_csv('foo.txt', header='group'))
newdf = pd.read_csv('foo.txt', index_col='group')

print(newdf)

       value
group       
a          2
b          1
c          2
```

Comment: To preserve column and index names,there're still NaN in the newdf?
I'd like to input like"a,2 apples\n b,1 beer\n" to the txt